# merging the columns in excel file and converting to time format using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the given excel data to a single time data using pandas in python .how can i do that . the format is as follows without header. I also want convert the 12.5 to 12.30 setup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm5n3.png)

the format should be like this

25 11 2020 12.5 -------------25-11-2020:12:30:00

Comment: What are the names of your columns for year, month, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need columns names `Day, Month, Year` and `Hour` for pass to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
L = [[25,11,2020,12.5],
     [25,11,2020,13.5],
     [25,11,2020,14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Day','Month','Year','Time'])

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df[['Day','Month','Year','Time']].rename(columns={'Time':'Hour'}))
print (df)
   Day  Month  Year  Time                Date
0   25     11  2020  12.5 2020-11-25 12:30:00
1   25     11  2020  13.5 2020-11-25 13:30:00
2   25     11  2020  14.0 2020-11-25 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

def process_row(row):
    date = map(str,map(int,row[:3]))
    date = '-'.join(date)
    date = pd.to_datetime(date,format='%d-%m-%Y')+timedelta(hours=row[3])
    return date
```

```
a=[[25,11,2020,12.5],[25,11,2020,13.5],[25,11,2020,14]]
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2       3
0   25  11  2020    12.5
1   25  11  2020    13.5
2   25  11  2020    14.0
```

```
a['date'] = a.apply(process_row,axis=1)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2       3       date
0   25  11  2020    12.5    2020-11-25 12:30:00
1   25  11  2020    13.5    2020-11-25 13:30:00
2   25  11  2020    14.0    2020-11-25 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it works for you. I create an custom function and use a datetime library

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.read_excel('./merging_excel_datetime.xlsx')
def createDate(x):
    return datetime.datetime(year=int(x.Year),day=int(x.Day),month=int(x.Month)) + datetime.timedelta(hours=x.Time)
df['Datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: createDate(x), axis=1)
df
```

**Output:**

[image]